# Have rules_cc use latest version of GCC

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I am using Bazel to build my project. One of the dependencies is Abseil, which in turn depends on rules_cc.

I notice that when I have multiple versions of GCC installed, rules_cc may be directing Bazel to use an older version of GCC even though I want the newest version of GCC to be used. To get around this, I have been manually editing `bazel-project/external/local_config_cc/BUILD` to reference the newest version of GCC.

Is there a better or "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add that flag to `.buildrc` (or to your `bazel build` invocation):

```
build --action_env=CC=/path/to/your/gcc
```

you can also set a `CXX` variable, but at this moment only a `CC` is used by Bazel

That approach use toolchain automatically generated by Bazel. You can also create your [own toolchain](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html), but it is a complicated process.

Comment: Thanks. I get this error specifically: "Compiling absl/strings/internal/utf8.cc failed: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@com_google_absl//absl/strings:internal':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'absl/strings/internal/utf8.cc':
  '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/stddef.h'
  '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/stdint.h'
  '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/limits.h'
  '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/syslimits.h'"

Comment: In bazel-project/external/local_config_cc/BUILD, I see lots of references to GCC 7 even though I have GCC 9 installed. For example, many of the entries for cxx_builtin_include_directories in the cc_toolchain_config rule are like this: ""/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include". Do you have any suggestions on getting Bazel to update this toolchain as well?